# How to split cell contents into several columns to create wide data?

Tags: r

I have a data set, data come from a multiple selection question in a Google form. However, when data are exported, all options selected by respondents are put in a single column, separated by commas. Like this.

```
df <- structure(list(teacher = c("Mary", "Andrew", "Rose", 
"Julia", "Richard"), grades = c("K, 1, 2, 3, 4", "1, 3, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "4, 5", 
"K, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I would like to split the cell contents into several columns to create wide data, so the final table looks like this:

```
df.wide <- structure(list(teacher = c("Mary", "Andrew", "Rose", 
"Julia", "Richard"), grade_k = c(1,0,0,0,1), grade_1 = c(1,1,1,0,1), grade_2 = 
c(1,0,1,0,1), grade_3 = c(1,1,1,0,1), grade_4=c(1,1,1,1,1), grade_5 = c(0,0,1,1,1)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

How can I do this in R. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easier option is with `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting at the `,`

```
library(qdapTools)
out <- +(mtabulate(strsplit(df$grades, ",\\s+")) > 0)
colnames(out) <- paste0("grade_", colnames(out))
cbind(df[1], out)
```

-output

```
  teacher grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4 grade_5 grade_K
1    Mary       1       1       1       1       0       1
2  Andrew       1       0       1       1       0       0
3    Rose       1       1       1       1       1       0
4   Julia       0       0       0       1       1       0
5 Richard       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

---

Or use `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df, "grades", sep = ",", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
  teacher grades_1 grades_2 grades_3 grades_4 grades_5 grades_K
1    Mary        1        1        1        1        0        1
2  Andrew        1        0        1        1        0        0
3    Rose        1        1        1        1        1        0
4   Julia        0        0        0        1        1        0
5 Richard        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fastDummies::dummy_cols`:

```
library(fastDummies)
x <- dummy_cols(df, selected_columns=c('grades'))
colnames(x) <- paste0("grade_", colnames(x))
cbind(df[1], x)
```

Output:

```
  teacher grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4 grade_5 grade_K
1    Mary       1       1       1       1       0       1
2  Andrew       1       0       1       1       0       0
3    Rose       1       1       1       1       1       0
4   Julia       0       0       0       1       1       0
5 Richard       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

ncols <- max(sapply(df$grades, \(x) str_count(x, ","))) + 1

separate(df, grades, into = paste0("col", seq(ncols)), sep = ", ") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -teacher) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = teacher, 
              names_from = value,
              names_prefix = "grade_",
              values_fn  = \(x) as.numeric(length(list(x)) > 0),
              values_fill = 0)
```

**Output**

```
  teacher grade_K grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4 grade_5
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Mary          1       1       1       1       1       0
2 Andrew        0       1       0       1       1       0
3 Rose          0       1       1       1       1       1
4 Julia         0       0       0       0       1       1
5 Richard       1       1       1       1       1       1
```